# Trying to get files from the old site

Tags: migrations

So I am currently trying to access our old website which was set up using Drupal. I re-downloaded all of the databases as well as the site files and set it up on a localhost.

The problem I am having is the only page shown is basically a white version of the old site with just the text of what was on it (without any of the CSS styles). When I try to click on a page it directs me to an "Access denied* page, unless I use the search box which just redirects me to a white page.

Does anyone know why I cannot get this site to work? I am just trying to access the articles that were published (which are located in the databases).

(I am running this on a local host version thru MAMP)

This is how the site appears.

> [image: ScreenShot of Site]

Comment: Could you right click, open developer tools, hit Network, refresh the page and check the domain it’s loading the files from matches the one you’re loading it from?

Comment: It matches the domain

Comment: not sure on Drupal 6, but could you check where the files are trying to be written to/read from exists and that Drupal has the right permissions to read/write to that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is a Drupal 7 site

1. Make sure you have `.htaccess` in your project root. You can get it [here](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess) - this should fix the access denied errors
2. If you have drush, run: `drush cc all` - this should fix the missing CSS (Drupal doesn't really serve pages directly, it makes cached versions of them. I'd say you caches are empty to they need to be rebuilt.

(If you aren't able to clear / rebuild the cache with drush, please try some of the alternative steps outlined [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/clearing-or-rebuilding-drupals-cache))

Comment: I'm sorry I should have clarified. I am running Drupal 6. I already have the .htaccess file yet it still doesn't do anything for the access denied. The only page it will allow me to reach is the localhost:8888/user page. and even so it still does nothing to the database when i create a new user. I am running this on a local host version thru MAMP btw.

Comment: Ah ok - no worries sorry I'm not familiar with Drupal 6 - hopefully someone else out there is!

Comment: well thanks for the input anyway man i still appreciate the effort!